# Fetch: Content-Type: application/json not changing in post method. Mode set to cors

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, fetch-api

I am new to using the fetch function and can't figure out why this fetch function wont change the headers. Specifically I can't seem to change the content-type to json making the API return a 415. I have tried with mode set to both 'cors' and 'no-cors' and neither seems to make the difference.

```
const fetchOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
}
await fetch("https://localhost:44375/api/users/login", fetchOptions)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
```

Here is a link to a picture of my Chrome console:

[image: Here is a link to a picture of my Chrome console]

As you can see, it is content-type plain text while also being in cors mode.

Comment: There should also be a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. Is that handled correctly? I can't reproduce this problem. Even posting to a bogus URL, the content-type is set correctly

Comment: This does seem to be the issue. It looks like my server wasn't handling that correctly so now I am off to figure out exactly what my server should be doing on that options request. Thank you!

Comment: Don't try and manually handle CORS pre-flight requests and headers. Whatever server-side stack you're using, I guarantee there's a mature, robust, pre-made CORS middleware available

Comment: I fixed it from your post. It was as simple as me adding to the cors policy on the server side that the content-type header was allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was server side and not client side. My web api was not allowing the Content-Type header to be changed due to a pre-flight OPTIONS request from the browser. This was fixed by properly setting up the cors policy on the server side.

In my case I am writing a C# api and it was as simple as adding WithHeaders to my policy:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: "DevOrigins",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
        builder.WithHeaders("Content-Type");
    })
);
```